# service spreadsheets timed out while accessing document with id, after copy some data between spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-performance

I need to copy data from one spreadsheet to another every day.
There is 13 columns and about 50k rows (counts of rows is growing with time).
But from time to time, after copy some data, function is stoped and I got Exception

```
"service spreadsheets timed out while accessing document with id".
```

Where is the problem ?
Do my function needs to optimise ?

```
function copyAll4() {
  let tss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  let ts = tss.getSheetByName('allOP');
  let ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  let dajurl = ui.prompt('paste source data url',
      '',
      ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL); 
  let urldozrodla= dajurl.getResponseText();
  
  let sss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(urldozrodla); 
  let ss = sss.getSheetByName('Sheet'); 
  let nrows_ss = ss.getMaxRows();
  
  let nrows_ts = ts.getMaxRows();
  ts.deleteRows(3, nrows_ts-2);
  ts.insertRowsAfter(2, nrows_ss-2);
    
  let SRange2 = ss.getRange("Sheet!B:C");
  let A1Range2 = SRange2.getA1Notation();
  let SData2 = SRange2.getValues();
  ts.getRange(A1Range2).setValues(SData2);
    
  let SRange9 = ss.getRange("Sheet!E:E");
  let A1Range9 = SRange9.getA1Notation();
  let SData9 = SRange9.getValues();
  ts.getRange(A1Range9).setValues(SData9);
    
  let SRange6 = ss.getRange("Sheet!G:K");
  let A1Range6 = SRange6.getA1Notation();
  let SData6 = SRange6.getValues();
  ts.getRange(A1Range6).setValues(SData6);
    
  let SRange10 = ss.getRange("Sheet!M:P");
  let A1Range10 = SRange10.getA1Notation();
  let SData10 = SRange10.getValues();
  ts.getRange(A1Range10).setValues(SData10);
    
  let SRange11 = ss.getRange("Sheet!V:V");
  let A1Range11 = SRange11.getA1Notation();
  let SData11 = SRange11.getValues();
  ts.getRange(A1Range11).setValues(SData11);
  
  
  let currentDate = new Date();
  ts.getRange("A1").setValue(currentDate);  
}
```

When I try to use `copyTo` I got
`Exception: The target range and the source range must be in the same spreadsheet.`

```
function copy_with_CopyTo() {
  let targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  let targetSheetTab = targetSheet.getSheetByName('allOP');
  let ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  let uiPaste = ui.prompt('paste source data url',
      '',
      ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  let urlSource= uiPaste.getResponseText();
  
  let sourcetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(urlSource); 
  let sourcetSheetTab = sourcetSheet.getSheetByName('Sheet'); 
  let sourcetSheetTabRows = sourcetSheetTab.getMaxRows();
  let targetSheetTabRows = targetSheetTab.getMaxRows();
      targetSheetTab.deleteRows(3, targetSheetTabRows-2);
      targetSheetTab.insertRowsAfter(2, sourcetSheetTabRows-2);
      
  let sourceRange = sourcetSheetTab.getDataRange();
      sourceRange.copyTo(targetSheetTab.getRange(1,1));
}
```

Comment: Welcome! As far as I understand your code, you want to copy the entire `B:V` range, but skip the `D,F,L`  and `Q:U` columns. In this case, you have to copy and paste the values five times into the array and into the target range (of course, this is a long time). Have you thought about copying B:V in one go with [**copyTo()**](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination,-options), as shown in [**this article**](http://www.saperis.io/blog/how-to-copy-a-row-to-another-sheet-with-google-apps-script), and then clearing the extra columns with **clear()**?

Comment: Hello @JohnSUN , the data is copying from one sheet to another sheet which is located in a different document. I have to use getValues not copyTo.

Comment: The title doesn't match bt he error mentioned in the question body. Please add the textual error message.

Comment: Hi, welcome to WebApps. commands like `getValues` and `setValues` are known to be time costly, and your code several of each. There might be several ways that you code could be made more efficient. Leavug aside the `copyTo` vs `get/setValues`, would you please explain the reasons why don't you copy all the columns from the source?

Comment: Hi @Tedinoz, copying all the columns means to copy 21 rows with 50k columns. It is almost two times more data. I have tested formula with one `getValues` and `setValues` and It took much more time and the error occurred more frequently.

Comment: In reply to @JohnSUN you said _"I have to use getValues not copyTo."_ Please elaborate on this because, with respect, I think you are wrong. I created a spreadsheet populated with data in 50K rows x 22 columns. I used `copyTo` to copy the source data from the source sheet/spreadsheet to a target sheet on the target spreadsheet. **Elapsed time was 29 seconds**. Add code to verify/rename the target sheet, delete columns, add date stamp, etc, and the whole think could be done in @ a minute. Compare that to your current execution time. Let me know if you'd like some example text.

Comment: @Tedinoz, thank you for trying to prove me I am might wrong :) It looks like you're right I have copied the tab by "Copy to" in tab menu and the entire tab was copied without problems in less than a minute. But I can't create a function to do this :/ When I try to use `copyTo` I got `Exception: The target range and the source range must be in the same spreadsheet.`
I added my function `copyTo` in qeustion above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function copy_with_CopyTo() {
  let targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  let targetSheetTab = targetSheet.getSheetByName('allOP');
  let ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  let uiPaste = ui.prompt('paste source data url',
      '',
      ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  let urlSource= uiPaste.getResponseText();
  let sourcetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(urlSource); 
  let sourcetSheetTab = sourcetSheet.getSheetByName('Sheet'); 
  sourcetSheetTab.copyTo(targetSheet)
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: data copy complete")
}
```

---

`copyTo(spreadsheet)` [Dec ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copytospreadsheet) is a SHEET method. You are copying the entire sheet from one spreadsheet to another. No need to insert or delete rows.

The new sheet will be named `Copy of Sheet`, and if that sheet name already exists in the target spreadsheet, then the content will be overwritten by `copyTo`.

Once the data has been copied, you can do any other housekeeping jobs, such as:

- rename the sheet (having checked for the existence of any existing name

---

```
// check if target sheet exists.
  // if yes, delete and create
  // if no, create
  let targetSheetname = "allOP"
  let tst = targetSheet.getSheetByName(targetSheetTab)
  if (!tst) {
    targetSheet.insertSheet(targetSheetname)
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: temp sheet doesn't exist so clean copy created")
  }
  else{
    targetSheet.deleteSheet(tst)
    targetSheet.insertSheet(targetSheetname)
    //Logger.log("DEBUG: target sheet exists so deleted and clean copy created")
  }
```

---

- Perhaps the header rows in the target are different than the source, but you could have a template in the target containing just the header rows and copy them to the data sheet
- if columns "A","D", etc are not required use, you could use the "Range.clear" method to delete the contents of those columns.